# Help me remember this EPIC hero call?

Tags: tournament, hand-history, heads-up, poker-history, final-table

Please help me remember this famous hand. It was an epic hero call with like 6 or 10 high. They were outdoors, which is odd for poker tournaments, and it was the final hand. There was lots of wind which ruffled the guy's long hair.

Basically the guy read the other guy as a busted straight draw and called the river all-in bluff and won the tournament. The other guy had 43 or 42, a busted straight draw, and the winner had like 6 or 10 high, can't quite remember.

Please I need the names of these guys!

Comment: any chance you remember what tournament it was? This sounds familiar to me but I can't put my finger on it either.

Comment: And what year was the tourney, and where? It sounds like 98 WSOP, when Stu won his third main. The one player I recall with long hair was Ron (Can't recall his last name). Ron was wearing a Tux, and finished fifth.

Comment: Rons last name was Stanley.

Comment: sorry I cant remember more, I was there, with a press pass covering the event

Comment: I do not remember the name of the player that came in second, he was not a pro, but an executive at Treasure Island

Answer (score 1):

Are you thinking of Isaac Haxton vs. Ryan Daut (https://youtu.be/pTLDuLCavzo)? It wasn't a hero call though, Haxton's bluff got through.

Answer (score 0):

Ryan riess did this with 10 high at a final table